# Fastlane - appstore vs testflight and when to call both?

Tags: app-store, testflight, fastlane

I'm a little confused with order of operations with these 2 actions. Right now we use "appstore" to push a new build to appstore connect and sets it up for submission. I'd like this same build to also be available on testflight for internal testing.

Given that both of these actions will upload the build for appstoreconnect, am I not doing double the work if I include both of them in a lane?

I don't see a "appstore + test" type of action that I could use here.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a conclusion for this? It seems odd to me that people would use both push to TestFlight AND push to app store. Once you push to TestFlight it's already in the app store, so you can just promote from within that. Unless people are lazy enough that they don't mind reuploading the same ipa to the App Store, just so they can do a release with only typing two words on a terminal